# Convert byte array of base64 encoding back to ASCII

Tags: javascript, java, json, base64

I am working on a web application that displays questions contained in json format sent by a Java rest endpoint. The questions have a text element but can also containt attachments in binary form (e.g picture, or movie) (see screenshot1). On the server the data is defined in XML which is used to generate the Java Classes using the tool xjc.

[image]

Now the general part of the application (that is displaying the questions) works BUT Im having troubles showing the pictures with the data URL technique  because the base64 binary is stored as an array of bytes. So instead of ASCII characters I get signed integers when I feed the value attribute into the img tag:

```
(`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,-119,80,78,71,13`<img)
```

This is visible if I open the debug perspective on the Java endpoint and check the variable of a question (see screenshot2).

[image]

Now, my initial thought was to change the data type of value from byte[] to String but as I am merely extending the base64 type of XML I am doubting that this is a wise thing to do.

I'd be grateful for your thoughts on this

The xsd file for content which is an element of "attachment"

```
<xs:element name="content">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:base64Binary">
            <xs:attribute name="filename" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

An example definition of a question

```
<question id="q1" type="yesno">
    <text>Is the organizations...?</text>
    <attachments>
        <attachment id="q1a1pic" mime="image/jpeg">
            <content filename="image.jpg" xml:lang="de>iVB....cut....
            </content>
        </attachments>
    </attachments>
</question>
```

The generated class Content:

```
public class Content {

@XmlValue
protected byte[] value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a custom XML Adapter was the missing puzzle piece. You can extend the javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters XMLAdapter class and implements marshal() and unmarshal() to perform the transformation.

```java
public class Base64Adapter extends XmlAdapter<byte[], String> {

  @Override
  public String unmarshal(byte[] v) throws Exception {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(v);
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] marshal(String v) throws Exception {
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(v);
  }
}
```

Afterwards, recompile the classes with xjc including the new Adapter in the bindings parameter: `"xjc.exe" -d "app\platform\src\main\java" -b src/main/resources/XMLBinding.xjc -p example.company.com src\main\resources\model.xsd`

See the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) for more details.